# Key binding not firing on OSX

Tags: macos, vim, neovim

I have a key command that isn't firing as expected in NeoVim. Below is the excerpt from my neovim config:

```
nnoremap <C-j> :wincmd j<cr>
nnoremap <C-k> :wincmd k<cr>
nnoremap <C-h> :wincmd h<cr>
nnoremap <C-l> :wincmd l<cr>
```

Applicable entry from :nmap shows the binding hasn't been overridden.

```
n  <C-H>       * :wincmd h<CR>
n  <NL>        * :wincmd j<CR>
n  <C-K>       * :wincmd k<CR>
n  <C-L>       * :wincmd l<CR>
```

But when pressing `<C-h>` nothing happens (except system bell). All the other directions work fine. Changing the binding to a different key has the same effect. Calling the ex command manually works fine.

This binding never gave me any trouble with Vim, although I've changed some plugins in the transition. Full vimrc is [here](https://github.com/icook/dotfiles/blob/master/nvimrc#L278).

NeoVim version info

```
NVIM 0.1.1 (compiled Dec 26 2015 18:48:21)
Build type: RelWithDebInfo
Compilation: /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/clang -Wconversion -O2 -g -DDISABLE_LOG -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-unused-parameter -Wstrict-prototypes -std=gnu99 -Wvla -fstack-protector-strong -fdiagnostics-color=auto -DINCLUDE_GENERATED_DECLARATIONS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I/tmp/neovim20151226-9038-13s73ki/neovim-0.1.1/build/config -I/tmp/neovim20151226-9038-13s73ki/neovim-0.1.1/src -I/tmp/neovim20151226-9038-13s73ki/neovim-0.1.1/deps-build/usr/include -I/tmp/neovim20151226-9038-13s73ki/neovim-0.1.1/deps-build/usr/include -I/tmp/neovim20151226-9038-13s73ki/neovim-0.1.1/deps-build/usr/include/luajit-2.0 -I/tmp/neovim20151226-9038-13s73ki/neovim-0.1.1/deps-build/usr/include -I/tmp/neovim20151226-9038-13s73ki/neovim-0.1.1/deps-build/usr/include -I/tmp/neovim20151226-9038-13s73ki/neovim-0.1.1/deps-build/usr/include -I/tmp/neovim20151226-9038-13s73ki/neovim-0.1.1/deps-build/usr/include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include -I/tmp/neovim20151226-9038-13s73ki/neovim-0.1.1/build/src/nvim/auto -I/tmp/neovim20151226-9038-13s73ki/neovim-0.1.1/build/include
Compiled by icook@Isaacs-MacBook-Pro.local

Optional features included (+) or not (-): +acl   +iconv    +jemalloc
For differences from Vim, see :help vim-differences

system vimrc file: "$VIM/sysinit.vim"
fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.1.1/share/nvim"
```

PS: I'm using iTerm2, but it seems to do the same thing in regular OSX Terminal.

Comment: NeoVim is probably equating control/H with a delete, and ignoring the map (call it a bug).

Comment: Ah, yes I've found the bug report on Github now.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's a bug in NeoVim, still unresolved.

https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/2048